# Как проверить PHP-функцию mail() ?

Tags: email, php

Как можно проверить PHP-функцию mail(), не отправляя письмо на проверочный E-mail?
Чтобы выводилось сообщение типа "Отправлено" (если функция работает), и "Не отправлено",
если функция не работает.

Comment: Никак скорее всего :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Только так наверное :) и никак иначе.

```
if (mail("test@example.com", "заголовок", "текст")) {
    echo 'Отправлено';
}
else {
    echo 'Не отправлено';
}
```

Comment: Я так и делал :-) Только не понимаю, как тут идёт проверка, если функция отключена. mail() возвращает какое-то значение?

Comment: @Виктор Павлов, возвращает true, если письмо было принято для передачи, иначе false. В мануале же всё написано :)
____
Да и "принято" вовсе не означает, что "доставлено" :)

Comment: Я, наверное, неправильно сформулировал вопрос. Нужна проверка работоспособности функции. Наверное, ваш код как раз для этого подходит. А насчёт "доставлено" понятно, что почтовый сервис может либо в спам кинуть, либо вообще не пропустить.